# Get ZeroDivisionError: float division in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the code below: highly simplified. I get `ZeroDivisionError: float division` 
Any value below one gives errors. Other times 5/365 gives the error. 
How do I fix?

```
import math

def top(  t):
    return ((.3 / 2) * t) / (.3 * math.sqrt(t))


t = 365/365
top= top(t)
print (top)
```

Comment: @Merlin KerrekSB wants you to type `5/365`, by itself, into the interpreter and see what the result is.

Comment: Type `5/365` into Python and see what it says. As the saying goes, teach a fish to debug...

Comment: @Merlin: "your method presupposes the knowledge "... Not true.  It presupposes that one can use the Python interpreter.  It doesn't require secret knowledge.  Just the ability to type.  Here's the point: try to type more and see what actually happens.  That's the best way to debug.

Comment: @Merlin It would show you that it's not functioning as you expect. With that expectation removed, you would be empowered to search for the answer to *why* 5/365 returns 0. The biggest obstacle to debugging is our assumptions about how something works that turn out to be incorrect.

Comment: @Merlin: At the very least, if you type `1/2` and you get `0`, it should make you think. With a little more luck, you'll deduce that you call `sqrt(0)` and thus divide by zero. Now you have a much better question, "why is 1/2 equal to 0?", and then you'll already hit one of the many SO questions to that end in the "possible duplicate" suggestions while you type the question... something along those lines.

Comment: @Ben: Lovely. "The biggest obstacle are our assumptions." That should be quotable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
t = 365/365
```

You are dividing two integers, so python is using integer division.  In integer division, the quotient is rounded down.  For example, `364/365` would be equal to `0`.  (`365/365` works because it is equal to `1`, which is still `1` rounded down.)

Instead, use float division, like so.

```
t = 365.0/365.0
```

Comment: This has changed in Python 3 -- in Python 3, you have to use `//` to get truncating division.

Comment: In fact it's not truncating division but floor division. http://python-history.blogspot.com.es/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html

Answer (score 9):

In addition to cheeken's answer, you can put the following at the top of your modules:

```
from __future__ import division
```

Doing so will make the division operator work the way you want it to i.e always perform a (close approximation of) true mathematical division. The default behaviour of the division operator (where it performs truncating integer division if the arguments happen to be bound to integers) was inherited from C, but it was eventually realised that it was not a great fit for a dynamically typed language like Python. In Python 3, this no longer happens.

In my Python 2 modules, I almost always import division from `__future__`, so that I can't get caught out by accidentally passing integers to a division operation I don't expect to truncate.

It's worth noting that `from __future__ import ...` statements have to be the *very* first thing in your module (I think you can have comments and a docstring before it, nothing else).  It's not really a normal import statement, even though it looks like one; it actually changes the way the Python interpreter reads your code, so it can't wait until runtime to be exectuted like a normal import statement. Also remember that `import __future__` does **not** have any of the magic effects of `from __future__ import ...`.

Comment: It's worth noting that `import __future__` does _not_ work the same way; you have to use the `from` version.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 exponent = math.exp(-(math.pow(x-mean,2)/(2*math.pow(stdev,2))))
```

A `ZeroDivisionError` is encountered when you try to divide by zero.