# pandas dataframe manipulation for division with 0

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 2 columns X and Y. I want to set up a new series which equals X when X=Y, and x/(Y-X) when X!=Y.

If try to do this:

```
df['temp'] = 0
df.loc[df.X == df.Y, 'temp'] = df.X
df.loc[df.X != df.Y, 'temp'] = df.X /(df.Y-df.X)
Z= df.temp
df = df.drop('temp', axis=1)
```

I get

> ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Is there a better way to do this than running loops?

Comment: replace 0 to np.nan

Comment: still get the same error

Comment: Your series of operations could be resulting into some though and hence the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,2,3,4,5], 'Y':[2,2,6,4,5]})
df
```

Use

```
Import numpy as np
df=df.assign(j=(np.where(df.X==df.Y, df.X, df.X.div(df.Y-df.X))))
df
```

Sol

```
 X  Y    j
0  1  2  1.0
1  2  2  2.0
2  3  6  1.0
3  4  4  4.0
4  5  5  5.0
```

Comment: this seems like the best solution, but somehow not working as in my edit above.

Comment: Issue is you dataformat. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479292/get-zerodivisionerror-float-division-in-python

Answer (score 1):

The condition should apply to both side

```
df['temp'] = 0
df.loc[df.X == df.Y, 'temp'] = df.X
df.loc[df.X != df.Y, 'temp'] = df.loc[df.X != df.Y,'X'] /(df.loc[df.X != df.Y,'Y']-df.loc[df.X != df.Y,'X'])
Z= df.temp
df = df.drop('temp', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
divisor = np.where(df.Y==df.X, 1, df.Y-df.X)

Z = df.X / divisor
```